# 4 Different HTML from single Craft 3 CMS on 4 different domains?

Tags: multi-site, multi-environment, multi-domain

Can we serve 4 different HTML from single Craft 3 CMS on 4 different domains?

working on a client project which has their 4 different domains for their different brands of the same business.

Is it possible, if yes how can we achieve it?

Thanks in Advance ..!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. How you organize the templates for each site is completely up to you. [Here's the docs on setting up multiple sites in Craft](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/sites.html#creating-a-site).

I would likely use a different layout template for each site. So when I extended at the top of an individual page template it would look like this.

```
{% extends "layouts/_site_one" %}
```

Or like this

```
{% extends "layouts/_site_two" %}
```